# Refer to a specific document in a BaseX DB using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

If I add two documents to a BaseX DB, let's say `normal.xml` and `normal2.xml`, is there a way to refer to each one individually?

I know about the `doc()` function, but it looks at the filesystem for their location, rather than in the database itself.

For instance, if I query with this: `doc("normal.xml")/name`, then I will get an error about `normal.xml` not being found.

I also tried: `basex:db("my-db-name")/doc("normal.xml")/name` and received the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up asking on the [BaseX mailing list](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/pipermail/basex-talk/2010-July/000494.html) and the answer I received is as follows:

```
for $doc in collection('test-db')
    where matches(document-uri($doc), 'example.xml')
return $doc
```

I also inquired as to why there was no direct way to reference the document one would want to extract data from in constant time, and the response was:

> This is due to the [XQuery data model](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-input-sources). XQuery has no formal notion of files inside a database/collection (Christian might correct me if I am wrong), 
>   so the collection() command returns any sequence of (document-)nodes for the given database. 
>   It is up to the user to pick those nodes he wants to process.
>
> We are currently looking for ideas on navigating collections more intuitively; something similar to 
>   "collection('db/path-to/document.xml')" that should still conform to the current W3C recommendation. 
>   As the subsequent document-uri() usually works well enough this is not too high on our priority list.

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 6):

The following query might help you:

```
for $doc in collection('your-db-name')
let $path := base-uri($doc)
where ends-with($path, 'normal.xml')
return $doc/name
```

Answer (score 4):

The `doc()` function is all you need assuming you know. Assuming you have created and opened a database named 'mydb,' if you add a document with the following command:

```
ADD TO your_name /some/path/on/filesystem.xml
```

You can always open the following document using:

```
XQUERY doc('mydb/your_name')
```

ADD TO will ignore the file name you gave it and use the name you specified in the URI.  Be warned though: there is no guarantee of uniqueness of 'your_name' when you run that command.  And if it's not unique, the (doc) function will throw a BaseX error (not part of XQuery standard) saying it matches more than one document.